wxPython: Cycling update of wx.ListCtrl DataTable from RS232 interface
I'm trying to make a program that reads in cycle the data from RS232 interface and shows it on wx.ListCtrl. The problem I have is that the data updates each 1 second and it's seems to be to high to undate all the wx.ListCtrl so the program crash (see crash message blow). I miht be using not approptiate gui control for my task, so could you suggest me another way to visualize the text table from RS232 stream?
This is the code I have.
def OnConn(self, event):
        """Say hello to the user."""
        # configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
        ser = serial.Serial(
            port='COM11',
            baudrate=115200,
            timeout=1,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
        )
        retConn = ser.isOpen()
        wx.MessageBox(f'Connection Open = {retConn}')
       
        while 1:
                bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
                data = ser.read(bytesToRead)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                dataRS232 = data.decode("utf-8")
                # Add the rows
                for item in dataRS232:
                    index = self.list.InsertItem(self.list.GetItemCount(), item[0])
                    for col, text in enumerate(item[1:]):
                        print(f'index = {index}    column =  {col}    text = {text}')
                        self.list.SetItem(index, col+1, text)
        ser.close()

Thanks in advance!
Before using GUI, I've used a console output, so I have no problems with data update.
Crash message:
Windows fatal exception: access violation


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00002e44 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2262 in MainLoop
  File "c:\users\tratkanov\projectfolder\pythonprojects\rs232_gui.py", line 169 in main
  File "c:\users\tratkanov\projectfolder\pythonprojects\rs232_gui.py", line 185 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 528 in runfile
  File "C:\Users\tratkanov\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16964\1439496246.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...
 


Generally, if the shown code runs in the main thread, the main loop of wxPython can't run, so problems may arise. If it runs in a different thread, GUI calls may cause a failure.

Thanks a lot! I was using the main thread for all the stuff. Would it be beneficial to split GUI and Serial Reader into different threads?

Sure. Then you can use wx.CallAfter (which is thread-safe) to transmit data from reader thread to main thread where it can be added to the list. If the data arrives very often slightly different approaches may be necessary.
